# Sort from sql using java?

Tags: java, sql, database, sorting

I have the following problem which could (I am hoping) have a standard solution.
I have a java application that interacts with the database and builds dynamically `SQL` strings.
So far I guess usual stuff.
Occusionally I need to have a sorting on the data and I use `ORDER By`. So far clear I guess.
Problem: I sometimes need to sort on a column that does not have the actual data but a short string that is a key to the actual data.
I mean:
`SELECT FROM MYTable WHERE MyTable.col1 = 'A' ORDER BY MyTable.col2  ASC`
And `col2` has values: `AB`, `BY`, `CY` which return sorted but are useless to me as these are keys to the actual values from a properties file and so the end result is not sorted.
What is the best way to solve this in a manner consistent with the way it currently works?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is _the end result_ in your case? Do you display this data in some grid, or something (and how)?

Comment: How many lines are concerned? I few => do it with SortedMap<K,V> if a lot, create a temp table in SQL from properties file

Comment: @Less:Yes they are displayed in a table by mapping to the values

Comment: How would I use a `SortedMap`?

Comment: For starters, you could check [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) to see if this fits your needs. Again, it depends on the situation you got going on over there, is it a lot of data, is it not (as Aubin said)...

Comment: I know what is `SortedMap`.How would I use it in this scenario I mean?

Comment: You could also use any collection and do a Collections.sort(...) on it. To do this you must implement a Comparator for your data type.

Comment: If you put your actual values in the map as keys, being that it's ordered on the key set, you'll get it sorted. Unfortunately, I don't understand what exactly do you do with the data you get from the result set, how do you retrieve the values from properties file, how do you map it to your display table, etc, so I cannot give the specific answer. If you claim that you know what a `SortedMap` is, you'll know whether you can use it, or not, in your particular scenario.

Answer (score 5):

If the data is not in the DB, then your choice is to either sort it in Java, or first insert the data from the property file into a temporary table and then join to that table and do the ORDER BY in SQL. If this is an operation that happens frequently, you might consider putting the properties into a permanent table.

Comment: 1)Is the creation of a `temporary` table supported by all database?2)I assume this can also be done from a java `Statement`, right?

Comment: It is supported in Oracle, MySql, SQL Server, Sybase. I'm not sure about any others, you could use a permanent table if you need to -- just key it by a unique id to prevent process clashes. Yes, you can do the creation of the temp table and the insert of the data using JDBC.