# How to handle multiple languages best in database applications?

Tags: java, sql, database, design-patterns, internationalization

I have a series of property files that are being used to display messages in various languages.
So depending on the current language settings a message could be displayed in English or French or German etc.
In my database I have various records and instead of the actual value I have put the key of the property file so that on retrieval of a record using that datum I can display the message in the corresponding language.
E.g. There could be a record in my database like:

`John| Smith| AQ| etc`

Where `AQ` in the corresponding property file could be displayed as `Doctor` or `Arzt` etc.
My problem is that I need to occusionally sort by these attributes whose values in the database though are the codes so sorting in the database is not possible.
From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975288/sort-from-sql-using-java) I got the suggestion to use temporary tables and sort but this is fine for me for 1 attribute.
I am looking for a more general solution to handle multiple property files and avoid if possible checks in the code:
e.g. `if this query sorts on X create this temp table` etc.
Is there a general solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than storing the language information in property files, store it in tables in your database.  Then it can all be done easily.

```
Records:
first | last  | messageid |
John  | Smith | 1         |

Messages:
messageid | language | message |
1         | English  | Mr.     |
1         | Spanish  | Sr.     |
2         | English  | Doctor  |
etc...
```

Then a query sorting by message in the local language would be like this:

```
select first, last, message from records r
    inner join messages m on m.messageid = r.messageid
    where language = [your current language]
    order by message
```

Answer (score 1):

Great question!

IMHO, you want to continue to use property files for localizing this kind of string - it allows you to use the built-in IL8N features of Java, and that saves you a lot of time.

In general, my recommendation is to store local strings for domain objects in the database - for instance, if you have a product database, and you need to store the product names, that's clearly a part of the domain; the people managing the products need to also manage the product names, and you want to be able to enforce business logic and referential integrity.

You could argue that this applies to the example you give - titles are part of the "person" domain, and should be managed in the database.

For user interface elements - the text on a button, the name of a menu item - properties files are absolutely right.

If you consider the "title" to be part of the user interface, or you don't want to move it because you have an established localization process, my recommendation is to do the sorting in Java, rather than SQL; depedning on how you connect to the database, there are plenty of ways to do that.

Comment: +1 This seems helpful.  I am not familiar with Java's I18N features, and was answering just from an SQL point of view.  If you want to use property files for Java ease of use while also having efficient sorting in the database, the information could be put in both places programmatically.  i.e. copy the relevant information from the properties files into the database so that it can be used for sorting.

Comment: @NevilleK:IMO it is better to avoid sorting in Java as I would prefer fetching results from the SQL server in parts instead of manipulating possibly hundrends of thousands or records.

Comment: It is indeed more efficient to sort in the DB - but the challenges with synchronizing a resource file with something in the DB is a huge pain, with lots of exciting failure modes...if you're sorting large numbers of records, you should bite the bullet and move everything into the DB.

Answer (score 0):

On application startup you could synchronize tables that contain the key, locale and actual message. These would be normal tables, so you can access them in the normal SQL queries.

But I would recommend to do the sorting you describe always in the application, because this seems really like application logic.

Comment: 1)The actual messages are not in tables but in property files 2)The sorting is not really application from my point of view as I could have hundrends of thousands of entries and I wouldn't want to do sorting in my application but get the result in "pages" from SQL server

Comment: @Jim with synchronize I meant that the values from the properties files are inserted into the tables.

Comment: But not temporary tables I guess

Comment: But temporaries last for one connection session,right? So how will this work?